# Error code for storage limit on Google Contact API

Tags: java, gdata-api, google-contacts-api

I have been working on Google Contact API. Google has a limit of 25MB of storage space for the contacts and maximum size of individual contact is 128KB while we can save 25000 contacts at max in Google Address book.

It respond with error code **403** and message **Insufficient storage quota** when user reaches to a limit of 25000 contacts.

Similarly it respond with error code **413** and message **Contact size limit exceeded** when size of the individual contact reaches beyond 128KB.

**I am wondering what will be the error code for storage limit i.e. If user reaches to storage of 25MB?
It would be nice if anybody can provide detailed list of then response code which Google sent for contact API call.**

Comment: The codes are standard HTTP response codes.  Google reveals what they all mean: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error .  The message you get with them will usually give a little more information on what has caused the problem

Comment: Note - this question is liable to get deleted because it doesn't show evidence of prior research - you might want to consider editing it - maybe including the link to google's contact API doc, which I assume you've read, which states "For information about the status codes, see the Google Data API protocol reference document.", which I guess you've also read but didn't make the connection that the API response / error codes were just HTTP response status codes.

Comment: Well There is no explanation for the storage quota error and messages it returns for storage quota error. At ur https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/2.0/basics there is no explanation for storage quota and the link provided on Google contact api, https://developers.google.com/apis/gdata/basics ,is broken.

Comment: I am using Batch operation api and I got these messages along with the error code by running my application.

Comment: OK - so that information needs to go in the question (note comments are not necessarily permanent...).  Also, you're right the link is broken - but if you google the actual link text "Google Data APIs Batch Processing documentation" - you find this link: https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/batch, which describes the http status codes that can be returned. The other thing you could do is create a dummy Google account - fill up the storage limit and test what happens.  I'll try to help you, but can only do that if you try stuff out. It is bad, I agree, that API doesn't document a full list.

Comment: Actually I get to know about 403 and 413 error code by dummy test account. I got these errors for 25K and 128K Limit respectively. Now I will try to produce 20MB error. Thank you for the help.